# SQL Server Query Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have an SQL database table, I want to find everything in a table where the 'Room' says 'DISPOSED', Insert 'DISPOSED' into the 'Status' field and then delete the entry in 'Room'.

Basically moving the entry from one field to another (if the 'Room' field has 'DISPOSED' in it)

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update table_name SET room='', Stauts='DISPOSED' where Room='DISPOSED'
```

OR

```
Update table_name SET room=null, Stauts='DISPOSED' where Room='DISPOSED'
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is

UPDATE table 
SET status = room, room = null
WHERE room = 'DISPOSED'